# Bitmap is being shrunk/cropped when drawn on by canvas

Tags: android

Set up: I have a simple class that extends image view to enable zooming, and that view has lines drawn on it via a canvas when a button is clicked. Code for drawing is as follows:

```
public void onBtnClick(View view){
        ZoomageView customView = findViewById(R.id.myZoomageView);//zoomageView is the class that extends imageView

       
        Bitmap myBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)customView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();//Bitmap gets the image from zoomageView
        Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);//new bitmap based on original and original is immutable
        Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);
        tempCanvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, null);
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setStrokeWidth(50);
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        tempCanvas.drawLine(0,0,5000,5000,p);
        customView.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), tempBitmap));
    }
```

This code should replace the image with an identical image that has lines drawn on top of it. This mostly works right, but for some reason the resulting image is cropped/shrunk, and I can't figure out why.

The image in the imageView turns from this:

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uA4Cm.png)

To this:

[Shrunk image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBc2k.png)

And that's the full image, it can't be zoomed out of any more (but can still be zoomed into normally).

If necessary, here is the code for zoomageView (I got it from github):

https://github.com/jsibbold/zoomage

Thank you for your time